# Rabin-Karp 2D pattern search runs slower than brute force

Tags: python, algorithm, 2d, rabin-karp

I have implemented the Rabin-Karp 2D algorithm for pattern searching in python. However, my implementation is slower than the brute force version over a 1000x2000 matrix. Please help me identify the bottle neck. Thanks, and I appreciate your comments.

Note 1: the code is right in finding the position where the pattern matches but runs slower, 1.23s v.s. 0.54s for brute force version on my computer.

Note 2: although one can come up with the worst-case such that Rabin-Karp could be as slow as brute force, the test case given is not designed on purpose to make it O(m(n-m+1)).

Disclaimer : Although this problem is an assignment problem in Algorithms, 4th Edition by Sedgewick and Wayne, it is not my homework. I am learning this algorithm.

Here is the code:

```
'''
Searches for a 2D pattern in a 2D text. Assumes that both the pattern and the 
text are rectangles of characters.
O(Mr * Nr * Nc), where Mr is the pattern row length, Nr is the text row length 
and Nc is the text column length

'''
MOD = 10**9+7

class RabinKarp2DV3(object):

    def __init__(self, rad, pattern):
        #Radix of the alphabet. Assumes ASCII characters
        self.RADIX = rad
        self.pattern = pattern
        self.height = len(pattern)
        self.width = len(pattern[0])
        self.factors_col = [0]*(self.height)
        self.factors_row = [0]*(self.width)
        self.factors_col[0] = 1
        for i in range(1, len(self.factors_col)):
            self.factors_col[i] = (self.RADIX * self.factors_col[i - 1]) % MOD
        self.factors_row[0] = 1
        for i in range(1, len(self.factors_row)):
            self.factors_row[i] = (self.RADIX * self.factors_row[i - 1]) % MOD
        hash1d_p = [0]*self.width
        self.hash2D(self.pattern, hash1d_p, self.width)
        self.patternHash = self.SingleHash(hash1d_p)
       

    def hash2D(self, data, hash1d, hei):
        for i in range(hei):
            hash1d[i] = 0
            for j in range(self.height):
                hash1d[i] = (self.RADIX * hash1d[i] + ord(data[j][i])) % MOD

    def rehash2D(self, data, hash1d, hei, j):
        for i in range(hei):
            hash1d[i] = self.RADIX*((hash1d[i] + MOD - self.factors_col[self.height-1] 
                    * ord(data[j][i])%MOD) % MOD) % MOD
            hash1d[i] = (hash1d[i] + ord(data[j+self.height][i])) % MOD

    def SingleHash(self, hash1d):
        res = 0
        for i in range(self.width):            
            res = (self.RADIX * res + hash1d[i]) % MOD
        return res

    def SingleReHash(self, hash, hash1d, pos):
        hash = self.RADIX*((hash + MOD - self.factors_row[self.width-1]*hash1d[pos]%MOD) % MOD) % MOD 
        hash = (hash + hash1d[pos+self.width]) % MOD   
        return hash
    
    
    def check(self, text, i, j):
        x, y = i, j
        for a in range(self.height):
            for b in range(self.width):
                if text[x][y] != self.pattern[a][b]:
                    return False
                y += 1
            x += 1
            y = j
        return True

    def search(self, text):
        hash1d = [0]*len(text[0])
        for i in range(len(text)-self.height+1):            
            if i == 0:
                self.hash2D(text, hash1d, len(text[0]))
            else:
                self.rehash2D(text, hash1d, len(text[0]), i-1)
            textHash = 0
            for j in range(len(text[0]) - self.width+1):
                if j == 0:
                    textHash = self.SingleHash(hash1d)
                else:
                    textHash = self.SingleReHash(textHash, hash1d, j-1)
                #print(i, j, textHash, patternHash)
                if textHash == self.patternHash and self.check(text, i, j):
                    return [i, j]
        return None

class BruteForce(object):

    def __init__(self, pattern):
        self.pattern = pattern
        self.height = len(pattern)
        self.width = len(pattern[0])
        
    def check(self, text, i, j):
        x, y = i, j
        for a in range(self.height):
            for b in range(self.width):
                if text[x][y] != self.pattern[a][b]:
                    return False
                y += 1
            x += 1
            y = j
        return True

    def search(self, text):
        for i in range(len(text)-self.height+1):                        
            for j in range(len(text[0]) - self.width+1):
                if self.check(text, i, j):
                    return [i, j]
        return None




    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    import random
    import string
    import time
    chars = string.ascii_uppercase
    im, jm = 1000, 2000
    text = []
    for i in range(im):
        s = ''
        for j in range(jm):
            s += random.choice(chars)
        text.append(s)        
    pattern = []
    for i in range(20):
        pattern.append(text[357+i][478:478+40])
    start_time = time.time()
    matcher = RabinKarp2DV3(256, pattern)
    print(matcher.search(text))
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))    
    start_time = time.time()
    matcher = BruteForce(pattern)
    print(matcher.search(text))
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: How big is the rectangle of text you're searching for?  It looks to me like the Rabin-Karp implementation won't be faster until it gets to about 25 characters wide.

Comment: Brute force is asymptotically optimal on random inputs, and the constant is hard to beat. The point of R--K is the worst-case behavior.

Comment: In the above code, the pattern rectangle is 20x40 as determined by the following two lines: for i in range(20): pattern.append(text[357+i][478:478+40]) Making the rectangle bigger didn't change the timing difference. So I suspect code had some inefficiency somewhere.

Comment: With the brute-force you are getting a lot of time-savings because the probability that your pattern matches a random sequence drops exponentially with the size/length of the pattern you search for. This means you terminate (exponentially) early for every location you test for.